# How to add new column and row to listview

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have Googled and Binged all morning and cannot find the information I require.

I am calling a SQL query on command that may be once, twice, etc. Every time the command is run, I want to add one column and then corresponding data for that specific column.

```
If reader(0).ToString = "Failed" Then
                    ListView1.View = View.Details
                    ListView1.Columns.Add("New Column", 20, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
                    Dim lvi As New ListViewItem
                    'Me.ListView1.Items.Add("Failed")                   listView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize)
ElseIf reader(0).ToString = "Passed" Then
ListView1.View = View.Details
                    ListView1.Columns.Add("New Column", 20, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
                    Dim lvi As New ListViewItem
                    'Me.ListView1.Items.Add("Passed")                   listView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize)
End If
```

This code works for adding all of the new columns every time the query is ran. But it adds the row data to the first column only.

Comment: You use the subitems collection of a LIstViewItem to add data to the columns.

Comment: btw.. that's not a terribly good use of a listview... You may want to consider using a datagrid instead. Listviews are more vertically "biased" than data grids.

Comment: How can I identify which column the data needs to go to?

Comment: item.subitems.add .. for the next or item.subitems(X) for a specific column starting at zero.

Comment: BUT. Dynamically adding columns can be tricky of you already have multiple rows. The control is NOT meant to be used that way.

Comment: Is a DataGrid better suited to add dynamically?

Comment: yes.. the listview is really meant for more specific well defined and constant  rows. LIke the folder contents details view in windows.